# Why does "Take Ownership" (and other) context menu (items) have selection limit?

Tags: windows, context-menu

Using ["Take Ownership Shortcut"](https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/1911-take-ownership-shortcut.html). Everything works fine, but it appears there are limits - when selecting more than 15 folders, "Take Ownership" context menu entry disappears. Same goes with files, 15 is maximum.

Where does that limit of 15 come from and why does it exist?

Comment: I don't know where the limit comes from, but its not just for take ownership. I added a custom item to that menu, and it disappears after selecting 16 or more files too. I guess it is to prevent the system from crashing because it will run 16 commands at the same time, or perhaps to prevent people from accidentally performing a task to hundreds of files.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have selected more than 15 files in File Explorer of Windows, options like Open, Print, and Edit disappear from the context menu. Here you can see the context menu has no options like those.

[image: Before registry applied]

❇️ This issue is not new to Windows 10. It also affects Windows 7, Windows 8/8.1 and Windows Vista. This is to avoid accidentally performing these actions on a large number of files at once, which can cause the computer to stop responding. To resolve this problem, there is registry tweak given by Microsoft.

- Open Registry Editor (regedit.exe). Go to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer` registry key. Create a 32-bit DWORD value named `MultipleInvokePromptMinimum` by right clicking the right pane in registry editor. Even if you are running 64-bit Windows, you still need to create a 32-bit DWORD value.

  [image: New DWORD registry key]
- Set its value data in *decimal* to the number of items in Explorer for which you wish to have Take Ownership context option visible. In the example below, I set the DWORD value data to 20 in decimal, so context menu commands will remain accessible for up to 20 selected files.

  [image: Set registry data]
- Then restart Explorer or sign out and sign in back to your PC. Now, you can select more than 15 files again and see that the missing Take Ownership context menu items are visible now.

  [image: Context menu visible]
- N.B. If you set up User Access Control (UAC) Prompt to full secure mode, then you see many UAC prompts pop up during take ownership. So take ownership some few files at once. Microsoft recommends "only increasing this value to a reasonable number in a controlled environment and only where users really need this value increased".

**Associated Articles::**

- [Microsoft Support: Context menus are shortened when more than 15 files are selected](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2022295/context-menus-are-shortened-when-more-than-15-files-are-selected)
- [WinAero: Windows 10 context menu items missing when more than 15 files are selected](http://winaero.com/blog/windows-10-context-menu-items-missing-when-more-than-15-files-are-selected/)
- [Ghacks: Fix Context Menu Items Missing In Windows Explorer](https://www.ghacks.net/2011/03/05/fix-context-menu-items-missing-in-windows-explorer/)
- [AskVG: [FIX] Open, Edit and Print Context Menu Items Missing in Windows 7 When 15+ Files Selected](http://www.askvg.com/fix-open-edit-and-print-context-menu-items-missing-in-windows-7-when-15-files-selected/)
- [SevenForums: Restore Missing "Open", "Print", and "Edit" Context Menu Items when more than 15 Files are Selected](https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/131470-context-menu-items-missing-fix-when-more-than-15-files-selected.html)